# Symfony configure Twig template for hinclude

Tags: symfony, templates

I was trying to obey http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#asynchronous-content-with-hinclude-js for setting up hinclude but I don't get the contents of `hinclude.html.twig`, instead I get "`::hinclude.html.twig`" displayed.

In `/app/config/config.yml` I have:

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    hinclude_default_template: "::hinclude.html.twig"
```

`hinclude.html.twig` resides in `/app/Ressources/views/default/hinclude.html.twig` and is nothing more than:

```
Loading....
```

The actual content is loaded correctly by hinclude.js but instead of displaying `Loading...` it just displays the template path as in the config file: `::hinclude.twig.html`

Also these configurations do not work:

```
hinclude_default_template: ::hinclude.html.twig
hinclude_default_template: "hinclude.html.twig"
hinclude_default_template: hinclude.html.twig
```

How can I use the Twig template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It figured out to be a misconfiguration...

**This doesn't work:**

```
hinclude_default_template: "::hinclude.html.twig"
hinclude_default_template: ":Default:hinclude.html.twig"
```

**This does work:**

```
hinclude_default_template: ":default:hinclude.html.twig"
```

You need to use lower case "default".